# Shrinkwrap not projecting onto mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, shrinkwrap

I'm basically trying to shrinkwrap this eye onto this face:
[image]

Unfortunately, after choosing project, and the axis accordingly, the eye failed to project onto the model. It's as if I never shrinkwrapped in the first place.

[image]

How do I project this eye onto the head? Also, any alternatives to shrinkwrap in order for me to project or wrap this eye onto the head? Thanks

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Done https://blend-exchange.com/b/oovJJVNz

Answer (score 1):

You've set it to project in its Y axis (the "Y" button on the modifier.)  If we enable the display of axes on your object, we can see what direction that is:

[image]

It's looking for the mesh in the direction of its Y axis, which is up, and it's not finding the mesh, therefore it doesn't do anything.

If we enable "affect only origins" on the toolbar, we can rotate its origins to some orientation where that projection *will* hit the mesh:

[image]

Comment: While it definitely worked, unfortunately, the eye looks distorted, like this:

Comment: While I don't see your image (maybe automoderated?) you should expect distortion when using a shrinkwrap modifier.

Comment: While I did follow as you suggested, unfortunately, the projected eye got deformed, like this: https://ibb.co/h9xNKSC

Comment: Okay, that picture is very different than what I said, and different than your question (SW is no longer projecting, period.)  However, again, you should expect distortion when using a shrinkwrap, even when (especially when) shrinkwrapping to the nearest surface point rather than projecting.

Comment: On second thought, I had to manually "adjust" the vertices by dragging the using the E and G keys to fit them onto the face.